# multi languages layout in grails application

Tags: grails

I'm developing multi languages Grails application ,i'm using [language selector plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/lang-selector) for choosing the languages, so for some languages like Arabic i need when the user chooses Arabic language i need all the layout to be from Right to left , how this can be done

Comment: Are you using graile for API only or is the frontend rendered as well?

Comment: @RazAbramov, sorry i couldn't get you , can you elaborate ?

Comment: Are you using gsp pages? or exposing an API endpoint for a client?

Comment: You need to change the active CSS page according to the language (a conditional LINK tag)

Comment: do you have any tutorials describing this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99355/discussion-between-raz-abramov-and-sherif).

Answer (score 1):

An example of different views for different languages:

def differentViews() {
        def currentLocale = RCU.getLocale(request)

```
    switch(currentLocale.language) {
        case englishLanguageCode:
            render view: 'englishView'
            break
        case arabicLanguageCode:
            render view: 'arabicView'
            break
        default:
            // pick a default view or error page, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: but is there a way to do this in the GSP itself , make it change the layout to right to left
because i think if i did it in the controller , i will end up with alot of switches
and also the example you provided may not help as it getting the LOCALE , what if the locale language for the user is English and the user wants to navigate the application in Arabic , this is why i'm not depending on the LOCALE , and applied language selector in the application and using i18n files.